# How can I choose Ruby version on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-1.9

I use Ruby 1.9.x syntax in my Rails 3 app, but after pushing it to Heroku it crashes due to older Ruby version (1.8). How can I control it?

Comment: You can now specify what version of ruby you wish to run on Cedar too: http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/5/9/multiple_ruby_version_support_on_heroku/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Heroku's current stack, Cedar, uses 1.9.2 by default. Cedar also supports [specifying the Ruby version in your Gemfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions). Currently, [1.9.2 and 1.9.3 are valid options](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions).

```
# Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "1.9.3"
...
```

More details are available in the Ruby support article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support

---

If you are currently using Aspen or Bamboo, you can switch to 1.9.2 by using the `stack:migrate` command:

```
$ heroku stack:migrate bamboo-mri-1.9.2
```

You cannot automatically migrate to the Cedar stack at this time, but there is a guide on how to do so: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-migration

Answer (score 4):

You can now [explicitly specify a Ruby version on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions).

Simply setup your `Gemfile` as so

```
# Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "1.9.3"

# Gems go here
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use the version I already had defined in the `.ruby-version` file so I ended up creating a buildpack that can be used before **heroku-buildpack-ruby** that injects the version from the .ruby-version into the `Gemfile`. It also support versions without patch or aliases.

https://github.com/platanus/heroku-buildpack-ruby-version

This way you can have your version defined only in one place.