# How can I specify the ruby version to use on Heroku from the RVM configuration files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rvm, gemfile

I'd like to use a specific version of ruby when running my app in production on Heroku.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613948/how-can-i-choose-ruby-version-on-heroku), you only have to add a line like `ruby "2.0.0"` in your Gemfile.

However, as I use RVM locally, I already specified the ruby version to use in a `.ruby-version` file in the root directory of the project that only contains the line `ruby-2.0.0-p0`.

To avoid code duplication, I'd like the version to be specified in only one place, so that I'm sure that the same version is always used in development and on Heroku.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Gemfile` is ruby code, so you can write some ruby to read the version from `.ruby-version` and pass that value to the `ruby` method, rather than a hard-coded version string.

If the `.ruby-version` file is in the same directory, something like this should work:

```
ruby File.read(".ruby-version").strip.split("-").first
```

If the `.ruby-version` file contains "1.9.3-p327", for example, that line would be equivalent to:

```
ruby "1.9.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't specify the patch level to be used on Heroku - they manage patch levels for you. You need to track their changelog to know when patch levels change. So you need to make sure you are using the same patch level locally which for Ruby 2.0.0 it's present p195.

Comment: Sorry I did not make myself clear I am not trying to specify the patchlevel used on Heroku but extract the version from the .ruby-version file and use it in the Gemfile, so that it the .ruby-version contains 1.9.3-psomething, the 1.9.3 is used and if I specify 2.0.0-psomething the 2.0.0 is used.

Comment: You can only do this with the gemfile, so, duplication required :( This feature request was opened, but is unlikely to be acted on. Seems rvm can read from the Gemfile? https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/issues/63